# make complains "missing separator (did you mean TAB?)"

Tags: compiling, make

While trying to install the `som_pak-3.1-NAcMoS.tar.gz` file, I've used the below commands:

```
$ tar xvf som_pak-3.1-NAcMoS.tar.gz
$ cd som_pak-3.1
$ cp makefile.unix makefile
$ make
$ cd ..
$ ln -s som_pak-3.1 $NACMOS_HOME/som_pak
```

But while executing the `make` command I'm getting the following error:

> *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.

- Can anybody tell me the reason for the error?
- Is there any packages need to include with this?

Comment: Where did you download that file from?

Answer (score 22):

The error you're encountering:

> *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?). Stop.

Means that the `makefile` contains spaces instead of Tab's. The `make` utility is notoriously picky about the use of <kbd>Space</kbd> instead of <kbd>Tab</kbd>. So it's likely that the `makefile` contains <kbd>Space</kbd> at the beginning of rule stanzas within the file.

#### Example

Let's say I have the following 3 `.c` files:

*hello.c*

```
char *
hello() 
{
  return "Hello";
}
```

*world.c*

```
char *
world() 
{
  return "world";
}
```

*main.c*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

/* Prototypes. */
char *hello();
char *world();

int
main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    printf("%s, %s!\n", hello(), world());
    return 0;
}
```

Say I have the following `Makefile`:

```
# The executable 'helloworld' depends on all 3 object files
helloworld: main.o hello.o world.o
        cc -o helloworld main.o hello.o world.o # Line starts with TAB!

# Build main.o (only requires main.c to exist)
main.o: main.c
        cc -c main.c # Line starts with TAB!

# Build hello.o (only requires hello.c to exist)
hello.o: hello.c
        cc -c hello.c # Line starts with TAB!

# Build world.o (only requires world.c to exist)
world.o: world.c
        cc -c world.c # Line starts with TAB!

#  Remove object files, executables (UNIX/Windows), Emacs backup files, 
#+ and core files
clean:
        rm -rf  *.o helloworld *~ *.core core # Line starts with TAB!
```

#### Now we try to build a target

When I run it against the target `helloworld`:

```
$ make helloworld
makefile:3: *** missing separator (did you mean TAB instead of 8 spaces?).  Stop.
```

Look familiar?

#### Fixing the issue

You can fix this by changing the <kbd>Spaces</kbd> to actual <kbd>Tab</kbd> characters. I used `vim` to repair my file. Simply open it:

```
$ vim makefile
```

And then run this command within:

```
:%s/^[ ]\+/^I/
```

**NOTE:** `^I` is a special character. Typing <kbd>^</kbd> followed by <kbd>I</kbd> will be interpreted differently compared to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

This will substitute all the lines that begin with 1 or more <kbd>Spaces</kbd> with an actual <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Now when I rerun my `helloworld` target:

```
$ make helloworld
cc -c main.c # Line starts with TAB!
cc -c hello.c # Line starts with TAB!
cc -c world.c # Line starts with TAB!
cc -o helloworld main.o hello.o world.o # Line starts with TAB!
```

#### References

- [Makefile for hello.c, world.c, and main.c](http://www.redantigua.com/c-make-hello-world-main.html)

Comment: I get E486 error pattern not found when I try to use that vim command

Comment: @DanielJacobson - if you have a new Q please ask it, comments aren't meant for asking new questions.

Comment: ^I just created ^I in the file itself instead of tab

Answer (score 4):

As the other answer suggested, Makefiles need tab characters, not space characters. I have my `.vimrc` set to automatically replace all tabs with spaces, so I have to manually set the reverse setting in individual Makefiles. The `vim` command that I use is as follows:

```
:%s/^[ ]\+/\t/g
```

Comment: I use this modeline (first line in Makefile) `# vim: set noet:`

Answer (score 1):

Note: The correct ways to deal with this particular problem is to correct the Makefile so that each action line of each recipe is indented using a single tab character, and then to submit a patch for it to the original developers.

This is an ugly hack, which work with recent versions of GNU `make` (if the issue is that the Makefile uses spaces instead of tabs, consistently):

```
make '.RECIPEPREFIX+='
```

This will set the special GNU `make` variable `.RECIPEPREFIX` to a single space. This variable, since GNU `make` 3.82 or so (2007), controls the character used for prefixing the action lines of the recipes.  If the variable is empty (as it is by default), tabs are used.

Example,

```
$ cat Makefile
all:
  echo hello
```

```
$ make '.RECIPEPREFIX+='
echo hello
hello
```

Example, showing its use with `>` (setting the variable inside the Makefile in this case):

```
$ cat Makefile
.RECIPEPREFIX = >
all:
> echo hello
```

```
$ make
echo hello
hello
```

See also:

- [Other Special Variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html) in the GNU `make` manual.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I had

```
.PHONY foo
```

And, I should have had

```
.PHONY: foo
```

I was getting this error,

```
❯ make foo
Makefile:1: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```